# split dates column in R when there are no sperators

Tags: r, date, formatting

I have a data set with date column with following format i.e. 19700101

How can I convert it as 1970-01-01 format

I tried zoo package in R but could not work it out. Can any one help me on this

Comment: What is the `class` of the `date` column ?

Comment: You can just do `as.Date('19700101', '%Y%m%d')` for converting to `Date` class

Comment: @akrun that is an answer not a comment?

Comment: I think your comment is what the OP is looking for (`split`).  You can post as an answer including my comment.

Comment: Class of the column is "Date". I need to split it to 1970-01-01 format

Comment: so what I meant in my earlier comment was if x is "19700101"
paste(substr(x,1,4),substr(x,5,6),substr(x,7,8),sep="-") would do this. But if it is already a date, I think what @akrun says is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(anytime)
anydate(19700101)
```